# Duplicate key in TreeMap

Tags: java

I have the below code for tree map where I store duplicate key and it seems overwrite the existing one.

```
TreeMap<String, Integer> tm=new TreeMap<>();
tm.put("vivek", 1);
tm.put("vivek", 2);
System.out.println(tm);
```

It prints `{vivek=2}` So it means map allow to overwrite on key basis?

Comment: Please read the javadoc of `TreeMap`.

Comment: *An object that maps keys to values. A map cannot contain duplicate keys; each key can map to at most one value.* - The very first line of the [Map interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html).

Comment: The very purpose of a map is to represent a series of key/value entries where each key is *unique*...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it doesn't show minimal understanding of the question being asked.

Comment: Yes, It silently overrides. One `key` have one `value` only. That is the latest inserted value with that key.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[`TreeMap#public V put(K key, V value)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#put%28K,%20V%29) API says

> Associates the specified value with the specified key in this map.
>   **If the map previously contained a mapping for the key, the old value is replaced.**

Answer (score 22):

All maps share the same basic properties, one of which is that all keys must be unique. Hence why `keySet()` returns a `Set`.

To do what you are looking for you need a Multimap - which is essentially a Map to a List.

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> multiMap;
```

To add an object get the list for that key, if it is null add a list then add your value to the list, otherwise just add your value to the existing list.

There are some multimap implementation available in various 3rd party libraries or it's easy enough to implement your own.