# Java TreeMap Duplicate Keys

Tags: java

I think I may have found a bug in Java.

I have a TreeMap in which I use a custom comparator. However, it seems when I put(key, value), on a key that already exists, it does not override the key, thus creating duplicate keys. I think I have verified this because I tried:

```
System.out.println(testMap.firstKey().equals(testMap.lastKey()));
```

And this prints out true. Anyone know why this is happening?

This is the comparator code:

```
private class TestComp implements Comparator<String> {
    @Override
    public int compare(String s1, String s2){

        if (s1.equals(s2)) {
            return 0;
        }
        int temp = otherMap.get(s1).compareTo(otherMap.get(s2));
        if (temp > 0) {
            return 1;
        }
        return -1;

    }
```

Comment: how many entries do you have in the `TreeMap`? If it's only one, first and last have to be the same ^^

Comment: Please show your complete code. From this line one can not evaluate what your are doing.

Comment: Are you sure your Comparator is transitive and consistent?

Comment: There is more than one entry and I have verfied this by printing out the size? What do you mean by transitive and consistent? Also, does it really matter what the comparator code is? Shouldn't Java automatically not allow duplicate keys in the entrySet?

Comment: Do the object in the map correctly implement `equals()` **and** `hashCode()`?

Comment: Check here for more info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21749386/duplicate-key-in-treemap

Comment: The keys are Strings so shouldn't equals and hashCode work fine?

Comment: @bkmoney: from the javadoc of TreeMap: "Note that the ordering maintained by a sorted map (whether or not an explicit comparator is provided) must be consistent with equals[...]" so you need to show you comparator that we can decide if it is.

Comment: @bkmoney TreeMap does not use equals or hashcode - it uses the Comparator you give it... So that's where the problem is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A comparator always needs to return consistent results, and when used in a TreeMap, be consistent with equals.

In this case your comparator violates the first constraint since it does not necessarily give consistent results.

**Example:** If for instance `otherMap` maps

```
"a" -> "someString"
"b" -> "someString"
```

then both `compare("a", "b")` and `compare("b", "a")` will return `-1`.

---

Note that if you change the implementation to

```
if (s1.equals(s2)) {
    return 0;
}
return otherMap.get(s1).compareTo(otherMap.get(s2));
```

you break the other criteria of being consistent with equals, since `otherMap.get(s1).compareTo(otherMap.get(s2))` might return `0` even though `s1` does not equal `s2`.

---

I've elaborated on this in a self-answered follow up question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29005998/how-to-create-a-treemap-with-a-comparator-based-on-external-values/29005999#29005999).

---

From the comments:

> Even if a comparator gives inconsistent results, shouldn't the Java language still not allow duplicate keys?

No, when you insert a key, the TreeMap will use the comparator to search the data structure to see if the key already exists. If the comparator gives inconsistent results, the TreeMap might **look in the wrong place** and conclude that the key does not exist, leading to undefined behavior.

Comment: Updated my answer a couple of seconds before your comment.

Comment: One more possibility: the comparator is not consistent with equals(). there are really tons of things that can go wrong, and it is impossible to know without more code.

Comment: "Mutable keys can lead to undefined behaviour". This may not be the solution for OP's problem, but is definitely something to be taken into account when using `Map` and deserves a +1

Comment: The keys are of type String so they are immutable correct? Even if a comparator gives inconsistent results, shouldn't the Java language still not allow duplicate keys?

Comment: @bkmoney No. It has specific example in java docs if the Comparator is inconsistent with equals():

Comment: `Caution should be exercised when using a comparator capable of imposing an ordering inconsistent with equals to order a sorted set (or sorted map). Suppose a sorted set (or sorted map) with an explicit comparator c is used with elements (or keys) drawn from a set S. If the ordering imposed by c on S is inconsistent with equals, the sorted set (or sorted map) will behave "strangely." In particular the sorted set (or sorted map) will violate the general contract for set (or map), which is defined in terms of equals.`

Comment: ok I posted the code and I'm pretty sure that this is "consistent with equals()" because it returns 0 if the two strings equal each other

Comment: @bkmoney as pointed out, your code may return the same result for comparing `b` to `a` and `a` to `b` and it isn't `0`, this means that the comparator imposes an inconsistent ordering. This case is explicitly covered in the documentation. TL;DR if you think you have found a bug in Java, you have a misunderstanding of the JDK.

Comment: @bkmoney, you're right. It is consistent with equals. But it has another problem. Answer updated.

Comment: I changed it to
`if (s1.equals(s2)) {
          return 0;
      }
      return otherMap.get(s1).compareTo(otherMap.get(s2))`

This still doesn't work even though it seems to be consistent?

Comment: @bkmoney this seems to be an XY problem. Why don't you explain what you actually want to do, and we will see if there is a solution using a `TreeMap` or some other `Map`. The main issue with your current approach is that if your `otherMap` changes then your `TreeMap` becomes completely broken...

Comment: @BoristheSpider, this should have been a comment on the question, not on the answer.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I've fixed my problem by using a different data structure (ArrayList) but I just posted this because I was curious why it didn't work. I think what you said is correct, since otherMap changed, this comparator becomes completely broken and there's no good way to write it.

Comment: @bkmoney, I posted a self-answered follow up question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29005998/how-to-create-a-treemap-with-a-comparator-based-on-external-values/29005999) with a working implementation.