# How to create a TreeMap with a comparator based on "external" values

Tags: java, treemap

I have a `Map<String, Integer> otherMap` which maps properties of strings to some associated integer values.

Now I would like a `TreeMap<String, String>` that orders the keys according to the associated integers in `otherMap`.

How should I tackle this problem, and what's important to keep in mind?

<sup>(This is a follow-up on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29005030/java-treemap-duplicate-keys).)</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When writing a comparator it's important to ensure that the results are consistent (i.e. are the same over time) and that it implements a [total order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order).

When using the comparator in a `TreeMap` it is also required that it is *consistent with equals*, which means that `c.compare(e1, e2)` return `0` if and only if `e1.equals(e2)`.

With this in mind, a correct comparator could be implemented as follows:

```
class MyComparator implements Comparator<String> {

    Map<String, Integer> otherMap;

    public MyComparator(Map<String, Integer> otherMap) {
        this.otherMap = otherMap;
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        int primary = otherMap.get(o1).compareTo(otherMap.get(o2));
        if (primary != 0)
            return primary;
        // Fall back on comparing the string keys to ensure consistent results
        return o1.compareTo(o2);
    }
}
```

(It should be noted that it is also important that `otherMap` never changes after it is passed to `MyComparator`.)

---

In Java 8, the idiomatic solution would look like

```
Comparator.comparing(k -> otherMap.get(k))
          .thenComparing(k -> k);
```