# Output a file based in a certain order based off a substring - Java

Tags: java

I am having a little bit of an issue. I am creating a little utility to order a large number of data and having a little trouble on how to go about it. I have got the file to read, loop, and output. I can see the substring values, but not sure how to go about to getting the output set correctly based on the substring value. Essentially want to output each line in descending order based off the substring. My code so far is as follows:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class fedOrganiser {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        //File Path
        Scanner fileIn = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\xxx\\Desktop\\Files\\ex1.txt"));
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("C:\\Users\\xxx\\Desktop\\Files\\filename.txt");
        while(fileIn.hasNextLine()==true) {//if no more lines to read, will return false
            //int orderBy = nextLine();
            System.out.println(fileIn.nextLine().substring(12,25));
            out.println(fileIn.nextLine() + "\n");
        }
        System.out.println("Completed");
        out.close();
    }
}
```

any idea or direction would be great :)

EDIT: instead of looping, i have read the entire file into memory as per here:

```
 String entireFileText = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\xxx\\Desktop\\Files\\ex1.txt"))
                    .useDelimiter("\\A").next();
                  System.out.println(entireFileText);
```

but not sure how to get this arranged in order?

data example for each row:

%[TIMESTAMP=1][EVENT=agentStateEvent1]

%[TIMESTAMP=8][EVENT=agentStateEvent8]

%[TIMESTAMP=6][EVENT=agentStateEvent6]

%[TIMESTAMP=5][EVENT=agentStateEvent5]

I want to order the above data in order of the TIMESTAMP.

output i want. Can be ascending or descending.

%[TIMESTAMP=1][EVENT=agentStateEvent1]

%[TIMESTAMP=5][EVENT=agentStateEvent5]

%[TIMESTAMP=6][EVENT=agentStateEvent6]

%[TIMESTAMP=8][EVENT=agentStateEvent8]

Comment: This looks to me as though you are going to simply output each line as you read it in.  If you want to really change the order, I believe you might have to read the entire file into memory and then sort it.

Comment: You can store each line in a collection e.g. ArrayList<String> and once the reading in complete sort the ArrayList using Collections.sort method which sort your Collection of line.

Comment: Can you please give a example of a line in your file so that we can have a better understanding what you are doing here and how to get it sorted?

Comment: @isuru-buddhika example provided

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As for the example lines provided you can use a `ArrayList` and get them sorted (As Ankush Soni suggested in comments)

To do that,
Create `ArrayList` before your loop as

```
ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
```

change your while() loop to,

```
while(fileIn.hasNextLine()==true) {
    lines.add(fileIn.nextLine());
}
```

After that sort the `ArrayList` using `Collections.sort()`

```
Collections.sort(lines);
```

Then write them to your `PrinWriter` with

```
for(String s : lines){
        out.println(s + "\n");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First, store the lines in a sorted map.

```
TreeMap<String,String> lines = new TreeMap<String,String>();
```

Loop through the file and store the lines:

```
while(fileIn.hasNextLine()==true) {//if no more lines to read, will return false
    String line = fileIn.nextLine();
    String key = line.substring(12,25);

    // hack to allow duplicate keys
    if (lines.containsKey(key)) {
        key = key + new Date().toString();
    }

    lines.put(key, line);
}
```

Then write the sorted lines in descending order to the output file:

```
for (String key : lines.descendingKeySet()) {
    out.println(lines.get(key) + "\n");
}
out.close();
```

Comment: Hi jovit, i am getting an error with the following line:

for (String key in lines.descendingKeySet()) {
  

Multiple markers at this line
 - The method descendingKeySet() is undefined for the type 
  SortedMap<String,String>
 - Syntax error on token "in", : expected

Comment: See my edited answer: ``TreeMap<String,String> lines = new TreeMap<String,String>();``

Comment: this does not quite work. If i give sample data of 1,2,3,12,14, it output puts it as 3,2,1,14,12

Comment: sorry just realised why, its due to the substring. my bad

Comment: final question, while looping through, if there are 2 lines with the same string, it will only output one of the two, any way to order ride that?

Comment: Java overrides the value stored in a key, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21749386/duplicate-key-in-treemap. However I edited the code to handle duplicate keys.