# Java - Iteration over arrayList & Insertion of 250k words into treeMap is taking huge time

Tags: java

I am implementing a Java based synonym finder, which will store the thesaurus of 250k words into a map and each associated googleWord into the txt file (1000 words in total) will be assigned as values for each of the thesaurus word if its the synonym of it.

Now, that I am doing that I am iterating over each Thesaurus word list and checking for its synonym using wordnet library and if the google word has one of those synonym word them I am assigning that value to Thesaurus map. Code block is provided below:

```
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public TreeMap fetchMap() throws IOException {

        generateThesaurusList();
        generateGoogleList();

        /** loop through the array of Thesaurus Words..*/
        for (int i=0; i<thesaurusList.size(); i++) {
            SynonymFinder sf = new SynonymFinder();

            // find the 
            ArrayList synonymList = sf.getSynonym(thesaurusList.get(i).toString().trim());          

            for (int j=0; j<synonymList.size(); j++) {
                if (googleList.contains(synonymList.get(j)));
                    hm.put(thesaurusList.get(i).toString().trim(), synonymList.get(j).toString().trim());
            }
        }
        return hm;
    }
```

But, the iteration of the list and its insertion is taking very huge time. Can someone suggest something to cater it fast.

*I have used HashMap for the same, but it was also slow..*

**Note: I must have to use some sort of map for storing data..**

My change after suggestions, but nothing helped out.

```
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public TreeMap fetchMap() throws IOException {

        generateThesaurusList();

        generateGoogleList();

        Set<String> gWords = new HashSet<>(googleList);

        int record =1;
        int loopcount=0;

        ArrayList thesaurusListing = removeDuplicates(thesaurusList);

         Map<String, Set<String>> tWordsWithSynonymsMatchingGoogleWords = new TreeMap<>();
        /** loop through the array of Google Words..*/
        for (int i=0; i<thesaurusListing.size(); i++) {
            SynonymFinder sf = new SynonymFinder();
            System.out.println(record);
            // find the 
            ArrayList synonymList = sf.getSynonym(thesaurusListing.get(i).toString().trim());           

            for (int j=0; j<synonymList.size(); j++) {

                if (googleList.contains(synonymList.get(j))) {

                    /**to avoid duplicate keys*/

                            tWords.put(thesaurusListing.get(i).toString().trim(), new HashSet<>(synonymList));

                }
            }

            for (String tWord : tWords.keySet()) {
                  tWords.get(tWord).retainAll(gWords);
                  tWordsWithSynonymsMatchingGoogleWords.put(tWord, tWords.get(tWord));
                }
            record++;
        }
        return (TreeMap) tWordsWithSynonymsMatchingGoogleWords;
    }
```

Comment: Sorry my comments typo.. I am looping through thesaurus..

Comment: Please suggest something.

Comment: In this place `hm.put(thesaurusList.get(i).toString().trim(), synonymList.get(j).toString().trim());` you override previously entered elements, because key value does not change. What is your intention of this part?

Comment: Yes because, google word can contain more than two words that belongs to thesaurus as a synonym.

Comment: Take a look, at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21749432/4677807 Mentionted code replace entry.

Comment: 1. trim your words once and for all, before entering thz loop. 2. use proper generic types (not ArrayList, but ArrayList<Something>. Use a HashSet for googleList: cotnains is O(1) on HashSet, vs. O(n) on lists. Use variables instead of repeating the same code again and again. Use foreach loops instead of traditional for loop and access by index. Check your `if` at the end: it contains an empty instruction. Indent your code correctly. Fix the algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code was missing part of creation, entry which will consist of {key, set}, but was {key, value}. Based on what you want to achieve, you need to intersect two sets. Here is example how you can approach that:

```
  public static Map<String, Set<String>> getThesaurusWordsWithSynonymsMatchingGoogleWords(
      Map<String, Set<String>> tWordsWithSynonyms, Set<String> gWords) {

    Map<String, Set<String>> tWordsWithSynonymsMatchingGoogleWords = new TreeMap<>();

    for (String tWord : tWordsWithSynonyms.keySet()) {
      tWordsWithSynonyms.get(tWord).retainAll(gWords);
      tWordsWithSynonymsMatchingGoogleWords.put(tWord, tWordsWithSynonyms.get(tWord));
    }

    return tWordsWithSynonymsMatchingGoogleWords;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Map<String, Set<String>> tWords = new HashMap<>();
    tWords.put("B", new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("d")));
    tWords.put("A", new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c")));
    tWords.put("C", new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("e")));

    Set<String> gWords = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("a", "b", "e"));

    System.out.println("Input -> thesaurusWordsWithSynonyms:");
    System.out.println(tWords);
    System.out.println("Input -> googleWords:");
    System.out.println(gWords);


    Map<String, Set<String>> result = getThesaurusWordsWithSynonymsMatchingGoogleWords(tWords, gWords);

    System.out.println("Input -> thesaurusWordsWithSynonymsMatchingGoogleWords:");
    System.out.println(result);

  }

}
```

To make all things working, firstly you should trim you thesaurus words and find their matching synonyms.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but your approach is just finding the commons between GoogleWords and Thesaurus. I have to get the synonym for the word and check in googleWords. If it exists than I have to map it with the thesaurus

Comment: I however, tried your solution but its still time consuming.. I have added it into your post.

Comment: @Jawad-Dev to add details or other, edit YOUR post, don't add info from you on others post

Comment: Okay sorry. Actually I am new here. I am updating it.